# MongoDB Aggregation to $group and conditionnally $addToSet

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following dummy collection, I want to extract exporting and importing countries for a given resource:

```
[{
    country: "France",
    exchange: {
        export: [{
            resource: "MILK",
            origin: ["Toulouse", "Bordeaux"]
        }],
        import: [{
            resource: "BEEF",
            origin: ["Lyon", "Marseille"]
        }]
    }
}, {
    country: "Spain",
    exchange: {
        export: [{
            resource: "PORK",
            origin: ["Madrid", "Barcelona"]
        }],
        import: [{
            resource: "MILK",
            origin: ["Valencia", "Bilbao"]
        }]
    }
}]
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
    resource: "MILK",
    exportingCountries: ["France"],
    importingCountries: ["Spain"]
}
```

I've been playing with `$group` but I can't find a way to conditionnally `$addToSet` countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to combine `exchange.export` and `exchange.import` arrays. This allows you to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `country` and then you need to get back `import` and `export` using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) operators, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            country: 1,
            resources: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    { $map: { input: "$exchange.export", in: { resource: "$$this.resource", exchange: "export" } } },
                    { $map: { input: "$exchange.import", in: { resource: "$$this.resource", exchange: "import" } } },
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$resources"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$resources.resource",
            resources: { $addToSet: { country: "$country", exchange: "$resources.exchange" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            resource: "$_id",
            importingCountries: { 
                $map: { 
                    input: { $filter: { input: "$resources", as: "r", cond: { $eq: [ "$$r.exchange", "import" ] } } },
                    in: "$$this.country" 
                } 
            },
            exportingCountries: { 
                $map: { 
                    input: { $filter: { input: "$resources", as: "r", cond: { $eq: [ "$$r.exchange", "export" ] } } },
                    in: "$$this.country" 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "resource" : "PORK", "importingCountries" : [ ], "exportingCountries" : [ "Spain" ] }
{ "resource" : "BEEF", "importingCountries" : [ "France" ], "exportingCountries" : [ ] }
{ "resource" : "MILK", "importingCountries" : [ "Spain" ], "exportingCountries" : [ "France" ] }
```

Comment: this works though it does require to add a `$match` to filter output resource. Thanks !